# Kivy Clock & Conditional Statements

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I created the variable timer_loop to run continuously. I'd like to make conditional statements with other variables, but I am unable to do so. Below is an example, I am trying to "do something" every 30 minutes if the switch is activated. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated :)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import datetime
import time

theRoot = Builder.load_string('''

StackLayout:
    orientation: 'lr-tb'
    padding: 10
    spacing: 5

    Label:
        text: "Zone 1 Valve"
        size_hint: .5, .1

    Switch:
        id: switch_id
        on_active: app.switch_on1(self, self.active)
        size_hint: .5, .1
''')

class theApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.timer_loop, 2)
        return theRoot

    def timer_loop(self, dt):  
        now_minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))

        if switch_on1.active & now.minute ==30 : # how do I use the varible switch_on1 in this loop for conditonal statements???
            print("Do something")
        else:
            print("Do nothing")

    def switch_on1(self, instance, value):
        if value is True:
            print("Switch 1 On")
        else:
            print("Switch 1 Off")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    theApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always advisable to see a class as a black box that we can establish input and obtain outputs and that in kivy can be done through properties, for example in this case you create the active property of `StackLayout` that reflects the active property of switch_id, and since `theRoot` is the `StackLayout` object that is visible from python we use it:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time

theRoot = Builder.load_string('''
StackLayout:
    active: switch_id.active # <---
    orientation: 'lr-tb'
    padding: 10
    spacing: 5

    Label:
        text: "Zone 1 Valve"
        size_hint: .5, .1

    Switch:
        id: switch_id
        size_hint: .5, .1
''')

class theApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.timer_loop, 2)
        return theRoot

    def timer_loop(self, dt):  
        now_minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
        if theRoot.active and now_minute == 30: # <---
            print("Do something")
        else:
            print("Do nothing")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    theApp().run()
```

As you realize it is not necessary to use `switch_on1` since the main condition is the triggering of the timer.

Comment: Your example was very helpful and worked perfectly. Thank you. I have one last question if you have the time:

Comment: If switch_id was within a popup, how would you make this work??                                                                                                     This is the last hurdle I have before I can move forward. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BradCarlton The logic would be the same, if you have problems then I invite you to publish a response showing the code you have tried.

Comment: eyllanesc, I have posted a new question with code. If you have time to take a look, you can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901880/kivy-clock-and-popup . Thank you for all the great advice